# Android Studio - Can't press About and Credits buttons

Tags: android, button

I cannot press the About and Credits buttons in my application, but I can press the other buttons. There are no errors in the logcat that I know of, so I am out of ideas.  Any advice?  I am kind of at a loss... Thank you to anyone who can help me!

```
 package natanrosenfeld.batteryinfo;
 import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import com.natanrosenfeld.batteryinfo.R;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;


public class SettingsActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements      
OnClickListener
{
Button start, clear;

Notification noti;
NotificationManager nmgr;
public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 0;




@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Utils.onActivityCreateSetTheme(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

    getInit();

    nmgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    noti = new Notification(R.drawable.flame, "Battery Temperature", System.currentTimeMillis());
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

    float temp = ((float) intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE, 0)) / 10;

    noti.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Battery Temperature", String.valueOf(temp) + " C", pIntent);
    noti.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

}
public void getInit()
{
    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
    clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn4);
    start.setOnClickListener(this);
    clear.setOnClickListener(this);
}



        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch(v.getId())
            {

        case R.id.btn:
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Info")
                    .setMessage("Battery Info © 2015 Natan Rosenfeld")
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // continue with delete
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // do nothing
                        }
                    })
                    .show();
            break;
        case R.id.btn2:
            Intent startcredits = new Intent(this, CreditsActivity.class);
            startActivity(startcredits);
            break;
                case R.id.btn3:
                nmgr.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID,noti);
                break;
                case R.id.btn4:
                nmgr.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);


    }

}

}
```

Comment: did you set the `OnClickListener`?

Comment: Oh jesus...i feel like an idiot!!! thank you

Answer (score 0):

I just set the OnClickListener like karaokyo nicely pointed out. *facepalm*